# получить количество товаров в заказе используя многотабличный запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

прошу помощи, вывожу список заказов, по каждому заказу надо вывести количество товаров, хотелось бы сделать это в запросе, но не получается. Не подскажите? Мой код привожу ниже

```sql
SELECT  o.uid, o.id as number_order, ..., count(oi.order_uid) as items_coun 
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN user as su ON su.hub_uid = seller_uid
INNER JOIN user as cu ON cu.hub_uid = client_uid
INNER JOIN orderstatus as st ON st.id = status_id
INNER JOIN orderitems as oi ON oi.order_uid = o.uid
```

Comment: почему вы считаете, что не получается? Какие данные на входе, что ожидаете получить на выходе?

Comment: @ArchDemon да я не считаю он реально не получается phpma вот что пишет "In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'admin_marketv2.o.uid'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" как я понял надо использовать группировку для агригирующих функцтй

Comment: @ArchDemon а на выходе хочу получитьт имена заказчика и покупаетеля и тому подобное и плюс количество товара по заказу и вот это не получается(

Comment: все правильно понял. вот и добавь group by

Comment: @Ипатьев aaaa добавил GROUP BY o.id а в вывод вместо count(oi.order_uid) сделал count(o.id) и всё вроде заработало. Это что правильно?!)

Comment: да там без разницы, можно любое поле считать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается всё легко) спасибо ребятам в комментариях, надо было просто добавить группировку , вот так

**SELECT**  o.uid, o.id as number_order, ..., **count(o.id)** as items_count 
**FROM** orders AS o 
**INNER** **JOIN** user as su **ON** su.hub_uid = seller_uid 
**INNER JOIN** user as cu **ON** cu.hub_uid = client_uid 
**INNER JOIN** orderstatus as st **ON** st.id = status_id 
**INNER JOIN** orderitems as oi **ON** oi.order_uid = o.uid 
**GROUP BY** o.id